# CTE TABLE WITH ORDER BY ERROR MESSAGE SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
;WITH myTree AS 
(
    SELECT 
        y.User_id, y.user_usercode, y.user_username,
        y.user_uplineID, 
        trans_WinLose, y.User_ID AS sourceID, trans_id,
        trans_Rolling, y.User_Level, 
        lvl1.User_Level AS Level_lvl1, lvl2.User_Level AS Level_lvl2,
        y.User_GivenPT, lvl1.User_GivenPT AS GivenPT_lvl1,
        lvl2.User_GivenPT AS GivenPT_lvl2, y.User_GivenComm,
        lvl1.User_GivenComm AS downline_Comm  
    FROM
        tbl_user y
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_trans x ON x.trans_Robot_ID = y.User_RobotID
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_user lvl1 ON y.user_uplineID = lvl1.User_ID 
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_user lvl2 ON lvl1.user_uplineID = lvl2.User_ID 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        u.User_ID, u.user_usercode, u.user_username, u.user_uplineID,
        t.trans_WinLose, t.sourceID AS sourceID, t.trans_Id, 
        t.trans_Rolling, u.User_Level, t.User_Level, t.Level_lvl1,
        u.User_GivenPT, t.User_GivenPT, t.GivenPT_lvl1, 
        u.User_GivenComm, t.User_GivenComm
    FROM
        myTree t
    INNER JOIN 
        tbl_user u ON t.user_uplineID = u.User_ID
 )
 SELECT * 
 FROM 
     (SELECT 
          mytree.*,
          (SELECT 
               CASE 
                  WHEN Level_lvl1 = 7 THEN GivenPT_lvl1 
                  WHEN level_lvl2 = 7 THEN User_GivenPT-GivenPT_Lvl2 
                  ELSE (CASE 
                           WHEN (User_GivenPT-GivenPT_lvl1) > 0 
                              THEN User_GivenPT - GivenPT_lvl1 
                              ELSE 0 
                        END) 
               END) AS Net_PT 
      FROM 
          Mytree 
      ORDER BY 
          mytree.trans_ID) AS c
```

I would like to order by mytree.trans_ID, but I get an error:

> Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
>   The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Side note, please format the sql statement properly - as is it is hard to read. You can use an online service for that: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: Why do you have the case statement with select? You don't need that select, the case statement can be by itself. Your derived query (select mytree.*...) can be moved to the top. It doesn't have to be a derived query and then you can use your order by.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to remove the outer query when querying the CTE - it doesn't seem to serve any purpose.

```
    ;with myTree as (
    select y.User_id,y.user_usercode,y.user_username,y.user_uplineID,trans_WinLose, y.User_ID as sourceID, trans_id,trans_Rolling,y.User_Level,lvl1.User_Level as Level_lvl1,lvl2.User_Level as Level_lvl2,y.User_GivenPT,lvl1.User_GivenPT as GivenPT_lvl1 ,lvl2.User_GivenPT as GivenPT_lvl2,y.User_GivenComm,lvl1.User_GivenComm as downline_Comm  from tbl_user y
         Inner join tbl_trans x on x.trans_Robot_ID = y.User_RobotID
            Inner join tbl_user lvl1 on y.user_uplineID = lvl1.User_ID 
            Inner join tbl_user lvl2 on lvl1.user_uplineID = lvl2.User_ID 
    union all
    select u.User_ID,u.user_usercode,u.user_username,u.user_uplineID,t.trans_WinLose, t.sourceID as sourceID, t.trans_Id,t.trans_Rolling,u.User_Level,t.User_Level,t.Level_lvl1,u.User_GivenPT,t.User_GivenPT,t.GivenPT_lvl1,u.User_GivenComm,t.User_GivenComm
          from myTree t
          inner join tbl_user u on t.user_uplineID = u.User_ID

     )
     SELECT mytree.*,
     (SELECT CASE 
     WHEN Level_lvl1=7 THEN GivenPT_lvl1 
     WHEN level_lvl2=7 THEN User_GivenPT-GivenPT_Lvl2 
     ELSE (CASE WHEN (User_GivenPT-GivenPT_lvl1) > 0 THEN User_GivenPT-GivenPT_lvl1 else 0 END) 
     END) as Net_PT 
     From Mytree order by mytree.trans_ID
```

Comment: Wrong Answer, this code can't use net_pt in select statement?

Comment: @JohnWalker: The answer is right given that this is the final query. The outer query doesn't serve any purpose. Also the select in (select case ...) doesn't serve any purpose, it can be simply a case without select.

Answer (score 0):

SQL behaves with data in Mathematics Sets manner. In Sets the order of data and elements are meaningless. So when you are dealing with CTE, sub-queries, views, inline table value functions etc, that are used to return a set of data, you are not allowed to order and sort them.

You need to sort data when you need to show them in output or you are using `TOP` or O`FFSET-Fetch` or etc commands, where the `Order By` helps these commands to work as they should be.

You should rewrite your query as:

```
;with myTree as (
select y.User_id,y.user_usercode,y.user_username,y.user_uplineID,trans_WinLose, y.User_ID as sourceID, trans_id,trans_Rolling,y.User_Level,lvl1.User_Level as Level_lvl1,lvl2.User_Level as Level_lvl2,y.User_GivenPT,lvl1.User_GivenPT as GivenPT_lvl1 ,lvl2.User_GivenPT as GivenPT_lvl2,y.User_GivenComm,lvl1.User_GivenComm as downline_Comm  from tbl_user y
     Inner join tbl_trans x on x.trans_Robot_ID = y.User_RobotID
        Inner join tbl_user lvl1 on y.user_uplineID = lvl1.User_ID 
        Inner join tbl_user lvl2 on lvl1.user_uplineID = lvl2.User_ID 
union all
select u.User_ID,u.user_usercode,u.user_username,u.user_uplineID,t.trans_WinLose, t.sourceID as sourceID, t.trans_Id,t.trans_Rolling,u.User_Level,t.User_Level,t.Level_lvl1,u.User_GivenPT,t.User_GivenPT,t.GivenPT_lvl1,u.User_GivenComm,t.User_GivenComm
      from myTree t
      inner join tbl_user u on t.user_uplineID = u.User_ID

 )select * from (SELECT mytree.*,
 (SELECT CASE 
 WHEN Level_lvl1=7 THEN GivenPT_lvl1 
 WHEN level_lvl2=7 THEN User_GivenPT-GivenPT_Lvl2 
 ELSE (CASE WHEN (User_GivenPT-GivenPT_lvl1) > 0 THEN User_GivenPT-GivenPT_lvl1 else 0 END) 
 END) as Net_PT 
 From Mytree) as c  
 order by c.trans_ID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
From Mytree order by mytree.trans_ID OFFSET 0 ROWS
```

change it to this, solved